# Есть ли примеры использования react-native + mobx + useForm

Tags: react-native, mobx

Что то не могу понять как использовать mobx и useForm. Есть компонент с инпутами который использует mobx. Через store он получает данные и данные должны попасть в инпуты. Но валидация данных должна быть через useForm. Есть ли примеры такого применения useForm?